# Updating Loop of Markov Matrix: subscript out of boundaries

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I am trying to multiply matrices. The values within the matrices represent probabilities that are different for each cycle. Therefore, I use loop for to update the values within the matrix. At the beginning it works fine, but then I get the feedback: subscript out of boundaries. The error message is showing my next values [4,] 210, 323, 467. Why are they not displayed at the bottom?

```
> initial_patient_distribtion <- c (1000,0,0)
> aaa <- c(1,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.4)
> bbb <- c(1, 0.2,0.3, 0.4, 0.5)
> ccc <- c(1, 0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1)
> 
> cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd[1,] <-initial_patient_distribtion
>  for (i in 2:length(aaa)){ 
+ trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd <- matrix (,nrow=3,ncol=3)
+ trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd[1,] <- c(aaa[i],bbb[i],ccc[i])
+ trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd[2,] <- c(0,0.5,0.5)
+ trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd[3,] <- c(0,0,1)
+ 
+ cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd[i,] <- cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd[i-1,]%*%(trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd)}
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, , value = c(210, 323, 467)) : 
  subscript out of bounds
> 
> cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 1000    0    0
[2,]  700  200  100
[3,]  420  310  270
```

Comment: For the purposes you seek the final matrix multiplication step is not needed. The transition probabilities have already been applied because you started with the initial state.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop goes to `length(aaa)` (5) and tries to access `cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd[i,]` when `i==5`. However, you'll see that `cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd[5,]` throws an error because the dimensions of that matrix are 3x3.

If your code does what you want otherwise, then you need to either change the ending index in your `for` loop to 3, or modify the dimensions of your matrix:

```
trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd <- matrix (,nrow=length(aaa),ncol=3)
```

Comment: Thanks, if I change then I'll get the following error Error in cycle_patient_distribution_dasa_no2nd[i - 1, ] %*% (trans_matrix_dasa_no2nd) : 
  non-conformable arguments

Comment: You're trying to multiply a 1x3 matrix with a 5x3 matrix. The inner dimensions need to be the same: either 1x5 x 5x3 or 1x3 x 3x3.